# Syntax for C# class definition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

My class is showing compilation errors:

```
namespace Zone.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Zone.Models;


    public class MyViewModel
    {
       public MyInfo Info { get; set; }
       public PageNumberResults { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The errors that am getting are the following:

```
Error 1 Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error 2 Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Error 3 Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration 
Error 4 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

My controller shows how the games are entered within the database through an interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using PagedList;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Zone.Models;

namespace Zone.Controllers
{ 
    public class GameController : Controller
    {
        private mydbEntities db = new mydbEntities();



        public ViewResult Index(string Ordering, int? CounterForPage)
        {

            var FullDatabaseItem = from b in db.tblGames
                                   select b;

            var Info = db.tblGames.Include(x => x.tblConsole).Where(UserInfo => UserInfo.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).ToList();

            switch (Ordering)
            {
                case "HeadlineName":
                    FullDatabaseItem = FullDatabaseItem.OrderBy(b => b.GameName);
                    break;
                case "DatePosted":
                    FullDatabaseItem = FullDatabaseItem.OrderBy(b => b.ReleaseYear);
                    break;
                case "DiscriptionDate":
                    FullDatabaseItem = FullDatabaseItem.OrderBy(b => b.ReleaseYear);
                    break;
                default:
                    FullDatabaseItem = FullDatabaseItem.OrderByDescending(b => b.ReleaseYear);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 3;
            int pageNumber = (CounterForPage ?? 1);
            var PageNumberResults = FullDatabaseItem.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

            if (PageNumberResults.Any())
            {

                return View(new MyViewModel()
                {
                    Info = info,
                    PageNumberResults = FullDatabaseItem.Count()
                });
            }

            return View("ErrorView");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the type in the second property:

```
   public ??? PageNumberResults { get; set; }
```

and you don't need the `using Zone.Models;` declaration, because your class is in that namespace.

Comment: I have added the following: 

public  MyInfo Info { get; set; }
       public int PageNumberResult { set; get;}

Comment: But MyInfo is complianing The type namespace name "MyInfo" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assemble reference?)

Comment: You probably need a `using` declaration for the namespace in which `MyInfo` is declared.  If it's in a different assembly you'll also need a reference to that assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is giving you error

```
public PageNumberResults { get; set; }
```

You need this format

visibilitymodifier Type Name

Ex : `public string Name { set;get;}`

Comment: I used int, object and string in where you given an example. What i am trying to achieve is paging with the following code:

var Info = db.tblGames.Include(x => x.tblConsole).Where(UserInfo => UserInfo.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).ToList();
return view (info)

but this complains and says Unreachable Code Dectected
so i craeted a class and tryed to call the return from there but am getting teh errors

Comment: did you use `public int PageNumberResult { set;get;}` ? The class should be able compile. but in some place if you are trying to set a different type to this variable, it will throw error.

Comment: you have to isolate your problem one by one. try to comment some code and build and see what errors your are getting. then fix that and so on

Comment: I have done that now that i built my application it says the following: 

The type namespace name "MyInfo" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assemble reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `using Zone.Models;` from your code. You're already in that namespace by the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have cited, not sure if you just didn't copy your controller completely, but you're missing the closing `}` on the class and the namespace.